# Run a FOR LOOP concurrently in Groovy?

Tags: multithreading, for-loop, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to find options where we can run a FOR loop concurrently in Groovy? I have a Jenkins file and I would like the for loop to run in parallel there

Something like the following code. I would like that all these for loops can run in parallel. Order is not a problem. It's just that the steps inside the for loop should be completed.

```
vars=[*,*,*,*,*]

for i in vars:
        '''steps'''
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the parallel directive. This is what you can do for a for loop. You should be able to use this code and adapt it to yours

```
def testList = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
def branches = [:] 

for (int i = 0; i < 4 ; i++) {
       int index=i, branch = i+1
            branches["branch_${branch}"] = { 
                    sh "echo 'node: ${NODE_NAME},  index: ${index}, i: ${i}, testListVal: " + testList[index] + "'"   
      }
}

parallel branches
```

Comment: Observe that `i` will always evaluate to `4` in the `sh` step, as it will refer to the loop variable which has been updated to `4` by the time the parallel steps are evaluated. This has bitten me several times.